# Can Google admob and Facebook audience network serve ads on the same app?

Tags: facebook-audience-network, admob

I have an app that is already running Google admob ads, but I want to also implement Facebook audience network into the app.

Will this be allowed by Google and Facebook? I've searched everywhere to see if I can get answer to this but didn't come across any. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this should be allowed. You can use multiple ad monetization networks within a single app. One of my friend is using admob's banner ads with startapp interstitial ads in his app. Also if you look closely some popular apps they are using multiple ad monetization network. Check this link for more info https://www.appbrain.com/stats/libraries/ad.